# Previously inserted rows disappear at call of PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am developing a server-side portion of a sport manager application using MySQL (5.1.67), with InnoDB as storage engine, and PHP (5.3.3).

When I try to execute a script containing any kind of query on several tables containing previously inserted rows, those rows disappear automatically. Note that no `DELETE` query is performed.

Example for table `users`:

I insert the rows into `users` by calling the **add_user.php** script:

```
<?php

function addUser($link, $username, $password, $email, $country, $president_id, $virtual)
{
    $response = array();

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, country, president_id, virtual) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssii", $username, $password, $email, $country, $president_id, $virtual);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if($result)
        {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "User successfully created";
            $response["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($link);

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else
        {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to create user";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}


require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['president_id']) && isset($_POST['virtual']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $president_id = $_POST['president_id'];
    $virtual = $_POST['virtual'];

    addUser($link, $username, $password, $email, $country, $president_id, $virtual);
}
else
{
    $response['script'] = "add_user";
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}


mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

then I execute some queries on `users` by calling the **start_season.php** script (in the following code I execute a generic `INSERT` query, since the resulting behavior is the same):

```
<?php

require_once "./add_user.php";
require_once "./add_club.php";
require_once "./add_president.php";
require_once "./add_coach.php";
require_once "./add_stadium.php";
require_once "./compete.php";
require_once "./generate_fixtures.php";
require_once "./remove_manager.php";


require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'user%'");


mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

and just like that all of the previous rows in `users` are gone.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` before `mysqli_stmt_close()` if you want to write the buffered statement data to the database permanently.  For example:

```
function addUser($link, $username, $password, $email, $country, $president_id, $virtual)
{
    $response = array();

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, country, president_id, virtual) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssii", $username, $password, $email, $country, $president_id, $virtual);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if($result)
        {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "User successfully created";
            $response["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($link);

            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else
        {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to create user";

            echo json_encode($response);
        }

        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
```

[The PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) for mysqli_stmt_close tells us ...

> **bool mysqli_stmt_close ( mysqli_stmt $stmt )**
>
> Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the
>   statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread
>   results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be
>   executed.

... which describes the exact behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I see I was missing an important procedure to correctly utilize a prepared query, unfortunately though, that did not solve the issue. Every time I call the **start_season.php** script the inserted rows still disappear.